# sql server db automatic update

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Since i'm not strong in asp.net, probably my question will sound silly. I've got remote sql server db and it has to be updated every month automatically. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: question contains insufficient detail and context.

Comment: i'm making news site on ASp.net. I need some programm, that deletes empty or old news from DB automatically every month. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break your question down into its constituent parts, which seem to be:

1. I need to delete some data
2. I need to perform a task (deleting data) at a certain time every month

**Deleting data**

You need to have *something* that can be used to delete data that fits a given set of criteria. Precisely how it does this will depend on how your application (I'm assuming you've got a server somewhere which hosts a website/application and a Sql Server database that contains the data for it). This could be:

- A web page / service
- An executable program
- A batch file

How you delete the data will be dependent on what tool (such as [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx), [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) or [plain SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) you've used to implement your data access, but will ultimately come down to something like:

```
DELETE
FROM    MyNewsTable
WHERE   NewsItemDate < '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000'
// '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000' will be whatever date you want 
// to delete news items for
```

**Performing a task at a certain time**

As you're using Sql Server you (may) have two choices (three if you count triggering it manually), these are:

- A [Sql Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) task
- A Windows [Scheduled Task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler)

Either of these can be used to trigger a program that you've written or, with the help of a 3rd party tool, call a web service / page.

Comment: thank u for help! it really helped me. Next time i'm gonna ask more detaily!

Comment: @Nate, not a problem - also bear in mind that you should ask *one* question, once you've worked out what you need, rather than a question that's actually made up of several different ones. You'll stand a much better chance of getting a decent answer that way =)